# Calculate the product of two spins

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, vectors

I have a problem saying that if a baryon with quarks $u$ and $d$ verify $\vec{s}_u+\vec{s}_d \equiv \vec{s}_{ud} = 1$, calculate $\langle \vec{s}_u \cdot \vec{s}_d \rangle$.
The solution says that:
$\langle \vec{s}_u \cdot \vec{s}_d \rangle = \langle \frac12\left(\vec{s}_{ud}^2 -\vec{s}_u^2 - \vec{s}_d^2\right)\rangle=\frac 12 \left(s_{ud}(s_{ud}+1)-2\cdot \frac 34 \right)= \frac14$.
I understand the first equality because is just vectorial algebra but not the second one. Why this $2$ and $3/4$?
Thanks!

Comment: I’ve removed a number of comments that should have been posted as answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize  your Casimir invariants
$$
\vec s_{ud}\cdot \vec s_{ud} = s_{ud}(s_{ud}+1)= 1(1+1)=2, \\
\vec s_{u}\cdot \vec s_{u} = s_{u}(s_{u}+1)= \tfrac{1}{2}( \tfrac{1}{2}+1)=3/4, \\
\vec s_{d}\cdot \vec s_{d} = \tfrac{1}{2}( \tfrac{1}{2}+1)=3/4.  \\
$$